# Symfony 4 - Is it possible to make variable command name?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am making test CLI-app with symfony 4 and I am wondering, is it possible to make single ClassCommand for multiple purposes?!

For example my test cli-app has several actions/commands but they are very similar. I don't like to duplicate code (also DRY-recommendations did nobody discard) so I thought it would be better to have single command, but depending on it's name choose, which algorithm to use. E.g. command name user:manager will execute one set of instructions and user:designer - another, and all it in one ClassCommand.

```
namespace App\Command;


use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UserCommand extends Command
{

    // some properties

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('user:somebody')
        // and other stuff
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // output code here
    }

}
```

For other commands for now I have to create another ClassCommand. Ok, I can extend it from UserCommand, but I still have to specify methods "configure" and "execute" (if it has to be overridden). Too many excess code, isn't it?

At the moment I have no idea how to make what I want.

Returning to the question: is it possible to make command-name dynamic?

Comment: You can pass a [required argument](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html#using-command-arguments) and do stuff from this argument `app:user manager` ˋapp:user designer` ...

Comment: @Smaïne, thank you, but it is not exactly what I want. The task is to make for several types of users a command which will print some information about user, and command call should look like "user:userType" with no arguments

Comment: For the Symfony console component, it is strictly one command per class.  The "no arguments" criteria seems strange to say the least.  Why would users care if they had to type a space instead of a :? In any event, extract the shared code between two or more commands into it's own class and then have multiple commands share the class.

Comment: Command argument is a correct approach here.

Comment: Got it. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible. But I don't think that would be the correct solution.

I would suggest one of the following approaches; either:

- create one command per set of instructions (e.g. one command class for `user:manager` and one for `user:designer`). You then use traits or extend from a common abstract class to do the work.
- or pass an argument to a single command class - e.g. `bin/console user:do-thing --type=designer`

> I can extend it from UserCommand, but I still have to specify methods "configure" and "execute" (if it has to be overridden). Too many excess code, isn't it?

You could specify both of those methods in your abstract UserCommand, and declare some abstract methods like `getCommandName()` which you would implement in your designer class.

Comment: _You then use traits or extend from a common abstract class to do the work_.

Abstract method in non-abstract class? How? Or it is speech form?

Comment: The abstract class that these commands extend would specify the abstract method. Forcing your concrete classes to implement the expected API.